# How to .slice() text by '.' '!' '?' without losing them? (regexp)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can i use regexp with .slice() in order to save my punctuation at the end of each line? Lets say i have a description which looks like this:

```
<div class="desc">We have text. About specific product? Or feature!</div>
```

I want it to look like this:

```
<div class="desc">
<ul>
<dd>We have text.</dd>
<dd>About specific product?</dd>
<dd>Or feature!</dd>
</ul>
```

for me jQuery is ok in this specific case, so i have build this:

```
jQuery(function() {
    var description = jQuery('div.desc');
    var sentences = description.text().split(/\.|\?|\!\s+/g),
    $wrapper = description.empty();

    jQuery.each(sentences, function(_, sentence) {
          jQuery('<dd>', {text: sentence}).appendTo($wrapper);
        });
        jQuery('.desc > dd').wrapAll("<ul></ul>");
        jQuery('.desc > ul > dd:last-child').remove();
});
```

and it works perfecly fine EXEPT -> slicing by "." "!" "?" - removes these signs. I need to keep them..

i also thought about something like:

```
var myStr = 'We have text. About specific product? Or feature!';
var strArray = myString.split('.');
```

after that i can use this (just for example):

```
alert('!' + strArray[1]);
```

BUT the thing is that description is always different. So if on one page "?" sign will be at the end of first sentence -> page number two will have it after sentence number 6.

Comment: You know your desired output is invalid HTML, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take `match` instead of `split`.

```js
var string = 'We have text. About specific product? Or feature!';

console.log(string.match(/.*?[.!?](\s+|$)/g));
```

Comment: He still has to split the string up though. How will this answer address that?

Comment: @ScottMarcus, i don't understand.

Comment: My mistake. I thought that `.match` simply returns a Boolean, not an Array. Got it confused with `.test()`.

Comment: @NinaScholz Thank you! Works great. 
The end result looks like this: (maybe somebody will need this)

jQuery(function() {
 var description = jQuery('div.desc');
 var sentences = description.text().match(/.*?[.!?](\s+|$)/g),
 $wrapper = description.empty();

 jQuery.each(sentences, function(_, sentence) {
       jQuery('<dd>', {text: sentence}).appendTo($wrapper);
    });
 jQuery('.desc > dd').wrapAll("<ul></ul>");
});

Answer (score -1):

If you use a capturing group in your regex, it will preserve the matched charactes.

```js
let myStr = 'We have text. About specific product? Or feature!';
let strArray = myStr.split(/([.?!])/);

console.log(strArray );
```